# I want to have an html button redirect me to another endpoint in flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, rest, flask

I'm making a hangman application that will ping Merriam-Webster's api's. I'm still in the initial phases of development and learning flask, but I wanted to render an html template in one endpoint that shows a button. This button, onClick, should redirect me to another endpoint, sort of like a "choose your mode" option.

The only thing is I can't figure out if I should use jquery, ajax, js, or just html, or how any of these actually work. I've only done GET requests before.

Here's a snippet of my endpoints followed by some html I found online:

```
    @app.route('/main', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def main_screen():
        return render_template('main.html')


    @app.route('/main/receive_data', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def data_screen():
        the_id = request.args.get('button_id')
        return "<p>Got it!</p>"
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <tr><td>
     <button id="socks.shirt.pants" type='button'> dummy text here</button>
     <div id='response'></div>
    </td></tr>
  </body>
  <script>
   $(document).read(function() {
      $("button").click(function(event){
         var the_id = event.target.id;
         $.ajax({
            url: "/recieve_data",
            type: "get",
            data: {button_id: the_id},
           success: function(response) {
           $("#response").html(response);
         },
          error: function(xhr) {
        //Do Something to handle error
        }
       });
     });
   });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first off you want:

correct:    $(document).**ready**(function() {

Not:    $(document).**read**(function() {

see if that helps your situation

Comment: That wasn't the issue